# Lots of 404 errors in Browser Console when Cache is disabled

Tags: angularjs, caching, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

We've come across a very strange issue when deploying a new website to it's Production environment that doesn't occur on staging.

In both Chrome & Firefox if we have the developer toolbox open and have the setting to disable the browser cache while it's open we get a bunch of 404 errors in the console tab.

The 404 errors are a mixture of images & ajax requests coming from the same domain.  All other resources, images, fonts, CDNs, ajax JSON objects from other domains load fine.

And when we allow the cache with the dev toolbox open or close the dev toolbox the issues goes away and everything loads fine. So it's not a major issue but I'm curious what could be causing it.

Has anyone come across something like this before?  Or do they have any ideas on how it could be debugged?

By the way our web app is built with AngularJS, but the issue occurs on images which are not using angular to get their `src`

Thanks!

### UPDATE

These are the error messages I see in the browser console:

```
GET http://example.com/data.service/-/action/getA/12345-G 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12185
n @ angular.js:11947
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11742
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16606
$eval @ angular.js:17913
$digest @ angular.js:17727
$apply @ angular.js:18021
l @ angular.js:12002
D @ angular.js:12211
w.onload @ angular.js:12139
GET http://example.com/data.service/-/action/get/67891-G 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12185
n @ angular.js:11947
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11742
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16606
$eval @ angular.js:17913
$digest @ angular.js:17727
$apply @ angular.js:18021
l @ angular.js:12002
D @ angular.js:12211
w.onload @ angular.js:12139
GET http://example.com/export.media/-/action/getLogo/format/id/123qwe 404 (Not Found)
GET http://example.com/export.media/-/action/getLogo/format/id/456asd 404 (Not Found)
GET http://example.com/export.media/-/action/getLogo/format/id/789zxc 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us specific example of a such request?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev I updated the question with more details. Thanks

Comment: @Holy Clear browser cache, enable cache and try to load the application. Do you still get 404 s? Have you confirmed that resources that you're trying to load are available?

Comment: @pahan, yea as I said in my question with the cache enabled it works, which is why it's not such a big issue but it's bugging me.  Yes I have confirmed the resources are available, when I open the URL in a new browser I can see they are there

Comment: To confirm whether the issue is with headers of the request, get the exact request including the headers when you get 404. Do that request in a tool like postman to see if it works.

Comment: @Holy Since the requests work when dev tool is closed, this could be a bug in chrome & Firefox dev tools,

Comment: @pahan, yea I thought so too but it's only occurring on our production env.  Not on our staging environment, and the only difference is the domain name for the resources we're requesting that are returning 404s